# How to reffer to a file in %appdata%\Folder in Autoit?

Tags: scripting, autoit

I need to reffer to a file in Autoit, let's call it's location %appdata%\folder\file.txt

How can I call to it in Autoit? I've seen %appdata% reffered as @AppDataCommonDir in it, but I can't get the full path right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the following?

```
$file = @AppDataCommonDir & "\folder\file.txt"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It's probably not correct, I havn't tested it, but it's my attempt of merging a full path. It has worked for me with other Macro-Folders like `@Temp`. So it is a solution, just the question is (as being rethorical) not the clearest statement of being one. So instead of asking if a possible solution is correct in a comment I decided to post it as a solution, so that if it works it can be marked as solved...

Answer (score 0):

## include

Local $filePath
$filePath = _PathFull("Folder\File.txt", @AppDataDir)

MsgBox (0, "Path", $filePath)